# Other method can't see in static method

Tags: c#, console-application, static-methods

I'm trying to use LINQ to Colletion but the problem is the method `ShowLINQ()` can't see in method `Main()`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShowLINQ();//Error line
    }

    public void ShowLINQ()
    {
        List<Element> elements = BuildList();
        var query = from d in elements
                    where d.AtomicNumber < 22
                    orderby d.Name
                    select d;

        foreach (Element d in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " " + d.AtomicNumber);
        }
    }
    Snippet...
}
```

Comment: `static` methods (which `Main` must be) cannot access instance methods. In this case, you probably just want to mark everything static.

Comment: `Main(..)` could exists without creating `new object of the class`, however  `ShowLINQ()` being non-static should only exist `when object is created` using new keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` means, basically, that you don't need to `new` an object to see it. It applies to *all instances of that class*.

Without `static`, you must `new` an object to see it.

If you want to communicate from a `static` method to another method, that other method must also be `static`.

Note however, that isn't the case the other way around. You can communicate from an instance method to a `static` method without issues.

So your solution is to mark your other methods `static`.. as well as any variables they share.

Comment: It's work! Thank you, I change all `public` to `static`